# Checking whether an element exists before proceeding to add an element

Tags: jquery

I wish to add a select list under the first 'li' of my list.

It works with this method.

```
$("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html("<select name='cao1' class='cao ops'></select>" 
+ $("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").html());
```

However, there's also another case where I would like to check whether the select list already exists within the 'li' item (to prevent adding duplicates). Do you have any recommendation on how I can do that?

What I'm thinking is something like.. (some pseudo code here..)

```
//If select list 'cao1' does not exist in this list item 

       // Add select list in this item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if($('ul.criteriallist li:eq(0) select[name="cao1"]').length === 0) {
    // add it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. May I check whether how come we're using '===' instead of '=='?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if($('ul.criteriallist li:first-child select').length == 0) {
//code to add dropdownlist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!(("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").find("select").length)){
    $("ul.criteriallist li:eq(0)").prepend("<select name='cao1' class='cao ops'></select>"); 
}
```